# Differentiating a matrix function with respect to a scalar

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, matrix-calculus

I would like to differentiate the following with respect to psi (partial):

$$
\operatorname{trace}\bigl((X^\top X)^{-\psi} P\bigr).
$$

Here we have that: 
$ X \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times n}, P \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ where $n,p \geq 0$ and $\psi \in [0,1] \subset \mathbb{R}$ is a scalar.

I have no idea how to start doing this as there are matrices involved…

Thank you!

Comment: Since $Y = X^\top X$ is an $n \times n$ matrix, do you know what $Y^t$ means for $t \in \Bbb{R}$?

Comment: Since $X^\top X$ is symmetric, you can work in a basis that it is diagonal and find
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \psi}(X^\top X)^{-\psi} = 
\frac{\partial}{\partial \psi} e^{-\psi\log( X^\top X)}
= -\log(X^\top X)( X^\top X )^{-\psi}
$$
Even though $X^\top X$ is a matrix, there is no issue in the order of matrices in
last expression. This is because $\log(X^\top X)$ commutes with $(X^\top X)^{-\psi}$
in the base where $X^\top X$ is diagonal and hence commutes in all bases.

Comment: See section 2.4.3 in http://www.mit.edu/~wingated/stuff_i_use/matrix_cookbook.pdf

Answer (score 0):

That follows is a simple consequence of Achille's post. Let $f:\psi\rightarrow trace((X^TX)^{-\psi}P)$.

Necessarily $n\leq p$ and $rank(X)=n$. Since $X^TX$ is PDS, $X^TX=Qdiag(\lambda_i)Q^T$ where $\lambda_i>0$ and $Q$ is orthogonal ; one has $(X^TX)^{-\psi}=Qdiag({\lambda_i}^{-\psi})Q^T$ and $\log(X^TX)=Qdiag(\log(\lambda_i))Q^T$.

Finally $f'(\psi)=-trace(log(X^TX)(X^TX)^{-\psi}P)=-trace(diag(\log(\lambda_i){\lambda_i}^{-\psi})R)$ where $R=[R_{i,j}]=Q^TPQ$. Thus $f'(\psi)=-\sum_i \log(\lambda_i){\lambda_i}^{-\psi}R_{i,i}.$